Как заменить Body для конкретного запроса в Network Inspector Rule?
Я создал правило для конкретных запросов в Android Studio Network Profiler, где мне нужно заменить код (с 200 на 401), а также body на:
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Access token expired: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cC...”
}

Проблема в том, что хотя я вижу в Network Profiler, что код ответа был заменен, body ответа нет (я получаю пустое body вместо error).


и ответ в Network Profiler выглядит так

Что я пропустил здесь? Почему error body ответа не появляется?
